# Why do I get no username/password dialog when using buddy-auth?

Tags: clojure

I'm using [buddy-auth](https://github.com/funcool/buddy-auth) and following the [tutorial](https://funcool.github.io/buddy-auth/latest/#example-httpbasic), when I run the [example application](https://github.com/funcool/buddy-auth/blob/master/examples/httpbasic/src/authexample/web.clj) I get a HTTP auth username/password dialog as expected, but in my own app I just get the "Unauthorized" exception, no dialog appears.

```
;; fn needs to return a non-falsey value to indicate a positive authentication, the returned value is stored under the `:identity` key in the request.
(defn auth-user [request authdata]
  (let [username (:username authdata)
        password (:password authdata)]
     username)) ;; FIXME: lookup username/password

(def auth-backend (http-basic-backend {:realm "MyApp" :authfn auth-user}))

;; my endpoint handler
(defn test-handler [r]
  (if (authenticated? r)
    (render (str "LOGGED IN" (:identity r)))
    (throw-unauthorized)))

;; ROUTES (compojure)
(defroutes app  
  (GET "/test" [] test-handler))

;; ring handler
(def site
  (-> (routes app)
      (wrap-authentication auth-backend) ;; <--- 
      (wrap-defaults)         
      (wrap-with-exception-handling)))
```

I don't think `auth-user` is ever called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I need `(wrap-authorization auth-backend)` too.

```
(def site
  (-> (routes app)
      (wrap-authentication auth-backend)
      (wrap-authorization auth-backend)
      (wrap-defaults)         
      (wrap-with-exception-handling)))
```